# Targert Display Mode - Switch from one to another

Tags: high-sierra, windows, target-display

I have an iMac 2011 on High Sierra and a computer (only unit) with Windows 10 on it.

When I plug the Win10 via MiniDisplayPort on the iMac 2011, no problem, I can see the monitor and can switch from Apple to Win10 via CMD+F2.

But, it's not working every time. When I plug in the cable, Win10 appears on the iMac and I can switch via CMD+F2. But two seconds later, sometimes more, sometimes not, I can't exit the Target Display Mode.

I had reset the NVRAM, didn't change.

So is it a knowing issue ?

Why sometimes can I switch and 2 seconds after, I can't ?

Comment: It does not seem possible to do what you are doing. Could you explain a little more about the cabling arrangement? I do not think you could have used a thunderbolt 2 cable. What  kind of port does the computer with Windows 10 have? I assume this computer is not a Mac.

Comment: I had plug in a minidisplay port câble from my GPU (from Win10) to the iMac. It has a minidisplay port too. Like I said, it works. But not every time...